# AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Python Limites

Tags: python, aws-lambda, package

I want to run my code on AWS lambda function. To do so, i need to import some python packages (i.e. pandas, numpy, sklearn, scipy)

I have two problems:
First of all, the size of (unzip) packaged python zip files is greater than 250MB.

Secondly, I got some error using scipy as well as sklearn as:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name
>   '_ccallback_c'

of

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named
>   'sklearn.**check_build._check_build'
>   ___________________________________________________________________________ Contents of /var/task/sklearn/__check_build:
>   __pycache** _check_build.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.sosetup.py
>   **init**.py
>   ___________________________________________________________________________ It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

I tried to reinstall many times... 
But still problems in sklearn and scipy.

Any idea?

sample code in AWS LambdaFunction:

```
import json
import numpy
import pandas
import sklearn
import scipy 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(event)
    return
```

Comment: Did you use Amazon Linux to download the required modules?

Comment: there are many blog posts about this: https://blog.orikami.nl/building-scipy-pandas-and-numpy-for-aws-lambda-python-3-6-cba9355b44e9

Comment: @KMo I did not use Amazon Linux.... How should I do? Can it overcome my problems?

Comment: @JDD It builds just scipy, pandas, and numpy. I need sklearn also. and when I put all them together, the size will be bigger than 230MB...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two issues.

The first (and easiest to solve) is that you need to install the relevant modules on a Linux distro comparable to Amazon Linux.

You can either do this using EC2 or in a Docker container with Amazon Linux on it.

The second issue (which is a bit trickier if not impossible to solve given the size of the modules you want to use) is that you need to get your deployment size down to under 250MB unzipped and under 50MB zipped.

Using relevant CFLAG when installing may get you some of the way there. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-shrink-numpy-scipy-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-your-data-product-4ec8d7e86ee4) for an idea of what might work.

If you are still over limit (which I suspect you will be) your only choice left will be to delete some of the files in the modules which you believe will not be used in your particular program. This is risky, often error prone and usually takes many attempts to get right. Using code coverage tools may help you here, as they can indicate which files are actually being used.

Comment: @SaeidSOHEILYKHAH while this is my answer to your question, you may want to consider if Lambda is the best deployment solution for whatever it is you are trying to achieve.