# Create AWS Lambda deployment package with imported libraries

Tags: python, aws-lambda, package

I am creating an AWS Lambda service which will process image and return some values from it. I need to import these libraries sklearn (KMeans), numpy and cv2.

I have already tried to import them trough layers. The problem is that the Lambda has maximum size unzipped to 250MB.

Is there any solution to import all of the above mentioned libraries and not exceed the maximum size?

Comment: try `S3` bucket. Upload your files to a bucket. Then access the bucket using its url or ARN

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have uplaoded the ZIP files to S3 and created Layer with link to the AWS but it does not change the size of the unzipped lambda function with layers included.

Comment: I've given an answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400174/4193581 if that's any help.